# Select overlapping date for booking

Tags: mysql, overlapping

Hello everyone I have the current situation on my MySQL:

id | start--------| end---------| person
1-| 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-10 | Mr. Yellow
2-| 2021-10-05 | 2021-10-08 | Mr. Orange
3-| 2021-10-03 | 2021-10-20 | Mr. Green
4-| 2021-10-20 | 2021-10-26 | Mr. Blue
5-| 2021-10-21 | 2021-10-28 | Mr. Pink

```
CREATE TABLE `booking` ( `id` INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `start` DATE NOT NULL , `end` DATE NOT NULL , `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = MyISAM; 

INSERT INTO `booking` (`id`, `start`, `end`, `name`) VALUES ('1', '2021-10-01', '2021-10-10', 'Mr. Yellow');<br>
INSERT INTO `booking` (`id`, `start`, `end`, `name`) VALUES ('2', '2021-10-05', '2021-10-08', 'Mr. Orange');<br>
INSERT INTO `booking` (`id`, `start`, `end`, `name`) VALUES ('3', '2021-10-03', '2021-10-20', 'Mr. Green');<br>
INSERT INTO `booking` (`id`, `start`, `end`, `name`) VALUES ('4', '2021-10-20', '2021-10-26', 'Mr. Blue');<br>
INSERT INTO `booking` (`id`, `start`, `end`, `name`) VALUES ('5', '2021-10-21', '2021-10-28', 'Mr. Pink');
```

Assume that this are some reservation on a hotel-resort, I would like to select which days are overlapping with which reservations

I want to find that:

From    3 to 4          we have 2 reservations overlapping: ID 1,3
From    5 to 8          we have 3 reservations overlapping: ID 1, 2, 3
From    9 to 10         we have 2 reservations overlapping: ID 1,3
From    21 to 26        we have 2 reservations overlapping: ID 4, 5

[Please check the image attached, for "see" easier the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UT3c.png)

Comment: I notice you are passing in a String value ('1' etc) for the `ID` column which is defined as `INT(2)`. That may cause problems. Since `ID` is auto-increment, leave `ID` off the `INSERT` statements and MySQL will automatically insert the ID values sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Calendar table and check the dates between the desired range, and join the booking table to get which user have booking on those dates:

Here is the creation of calendar table and booking table :

```
CREATE TABLE booking ( id INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , start DATE NOT NULL , end DATE NOT NULL , name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (id));
INSERT INTO booking (id, start, end, name) VALUES ('1', '2021-10-01', '2021-10-10', 'Mr. Yellow');
INSERT INTO booking (id, start, end, name) VALUES ('2', '2021-10-05', '2021-10-08', 'Mr. Orange');
INSERT INTO booking (id, start, end, name) VALUES ('3', '2021-10-03', '2021-10-20', 'Mr. Green');
INSERT INTO booking (id, start, end, name) VALUES ('4', '2021-10-20', '2021-10-26', 'Mr. Blue');
INSERT INTO booking (id, start, end, name) VALUES ('5', '2021-10-21', '2021-10-28', 'Mr. Pink');

CREATE TABLE time_dimension (
        id                      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  -- year*10000+month*100+day
        db_date                 DATE NOT NULL,
        year                    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        month                   INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 12
        day                     INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 31
        quarter                 INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 4
        week                    INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 52/53
        day_name                VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- 'Monday', 'Tuesday'...
        month_name              VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- 'January', 'February'...
        holiday_flag            CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f' CHECK (holiday_flag in ('t', 'f')),
        weekend_flag            CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f' CHECK (weekday_flag in ('t', 'f')),
        event                   VARCHAR(50),
        UNIQUE td_ymd_idx (year,month,day),
        UNIQUE td_dbdate_idx (db_date)

) Engine=MyISAM;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fill_date_dimension;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_date_dimension(IN startdate DATE,IN stopdate DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE currentdate DATE;
    SET currentdate = startdate;
    WHILE currentdate < stopdate DO
        INSERT INTO time_dimension VALUES (
                        YEAR(currentdate)*10000+MONTH(currentdate)*100 + DAY(currentdate),
                        currentdate,
                        YEAR(currentdate),
                        MONTH(currentdate),
                        DAY(currentdate),
                        QUARTER(currentdate),
                        WEEKOFYEAR(currentdate),
                        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%W'),
                        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%M'),
                        'f',
                        CASE DAYOFWEEK(currentdate) WHEN 1 THEN 't' WHEN 7 then 't' ELSE 'f' END,
                        NULL);
        SET currentdate = ADDDATE(currentdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

TRUNCATE TABLE time_dimension;

CALL fill_date_dimension('2020-01-01','2022-01-01');
```

And SQL :

```
select d.db_date,b.name from time_dimension d
inner join booking b on d.db_date between b.start and b.end
where db_date between '2021-10-01'  and '2021-10-10'
```

Note:

1. its looking for dates between `'2021-10-01'  and '2021-10-10'`
2. You can group by dates and count them to see which date has how many bookings like this:

---

```
select d.db_date, count(*) from time_dimension d
inner join booking b on d.db_date between b.start and b.end
where db_date between '2021-10-01'  and '2021-10-10'
group by d.db_date
```

---

Fiddle is [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eXrAbBXoK9pPtLRgG9Y3rv/1)

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed reply, it's pretty tricky, and I was hoping, if there is another way also to find this out.

Comment: which side is the tricky part ? i even shared the scripts.